# How to get access to var in HTML from JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in my HTML file "covidCases". And I need to change its value. I get the data in my JS file "covidData". And I don't know how to send this data to the var which I have in my HTML file. I will appreciate any help. I just don't know if it is possible or is there a better way to send my data from js to the chart in HTML file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      var covidCases = 150;
      function drawChart() {
        var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ["Task", "Hours per Day"],
          ["Cases", covidCases],
          ["Eat", 2],
          ["Commute", 2],
          ["Watch TV", 2],
          ["Sleep", 7],
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: "My Daily Activities",
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
          document.getElementById("piechart")
        );

        chart.draw(tableData, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  const url = "https://api.caw.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/ukraine?strict=true";

  https.get(url, function (response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function (data) {
      const covidData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(covidData.cases);
      v;
    });
    res.send("Success");
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server is tunning on port 3000.");
});
```

Comment: You actually don't need to backend js code to get the data. Is it necessary for you? You can use fetch or axios to get the data from the api.

Comment: Yea, but i decided to do it like that. I just want to send data to my html doc so i can change the chart.

Comment: What is the <script src="../app.js"></script>? Is it your js code above?

Comment: Yes) this way I link it to my html

Comment: Then, you don't need this line in you html.  You should run your app.js in nodejs first and then run your html to fetch data from it.

Comment: Look. The idea is to use node to get coronavirus data from api.  I did it, I got this data. Now I want to show this data in HTML in a form of google chart. I copied google chart code in my HTML. And I don't know how to paste this data, which I get in node, to my HTMLso I can show it in the chart.

Comment: You are not running your express.js server in your browser, so you don't need to include app.js in your HTML. Also, I updated my answer to use a simple fetch action to console.log the covidCases you want in the browser. Please check if this works. Before you run your page, make sure your express js server is running.

Comment: I tried and that and that's what i got in console:
index.html:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
localhost:3000/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

I don't know what that is because I haven't learned it yet)